# Model falling down when starting

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi!

I am having problems with my model, it oftens falls to the ground when starting. This is totally random behaviour though... Any ideas why this can be happening?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3381/model-falling-down-when-starting/) by [atenea](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/403/atenea/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2013-06-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mrit91](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/400/mrit91/) on 2013-07-02**:
Could you explain your question a bit more. Do you want to switch off the gravity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

All the links are in exactly the same position, which is probably not what you want. You should set the pose of each link relative to the parent model.

The pose of the model should also be set so that it doesn't penetrate the ground plane on start.

It can be helpful to start the simulation paused in order to see the initial configuration of your model. Pass 'gazebo' the '-u' command line argument to start paused.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [atenea](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/403/atenea/) on 2013-07-25**:
Thanks!!! That was it. I fixed the poses and now it is working.